# filter data in text file and load into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, bash, sed, grep

I have a text file with the below format:

```
Text: htpps:/xxx
Expiry: ddmm/yyyy
object_id: 00
object: ABC
auth: 333
RequestID: 1234

Text: htpps:/yyy
Expiry: ddmm/yyyy
object_id: 01
object: NNN
auth: 222
RequestID: 3456    

and so on
...
```

1. I want to delete all lines with the exception of lines with prefix "Expiry:" "object:" and "object_id:"
2. then load it into a table in postgresql

Would really appreciate your help on the above two.

thanks
Nick

Comment: Can you also please share what you already tried? The DB table schema helps too..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there will be other methods, but I found an iterative approach if every object has the same format of

```
Text: htpps:/xxx
Expiry: ddmm/yyyy
object_id: 00
object: ABC
auth: 333
RequestID: 1234
```

Then you can transform the above with

```
more test.txt | awk '{ printf "%s\n", $2 }' | tr  '\n' ',' | sed 's/,,/\n/' | sed '$ s/.$//'
```

and, for your example it will generate the entries in CSV format

```
htpps:/xxx,ddmm/yyyy,00,ABC,333,1234
htpps:/yyy,ddmm/yyyy,01,NNN,222,3456
```

The above code does:

- `awk '{ printf "%s\n", $2 }'`: prints only the second element for each row
- `tr  '\n' ','`: transform new lines in `,`
- `sed 's/,,/\n/'`: removes the empty lines
- `sed '$ s/.$//'`: removes the trailing `,`

Of course this is probably an oversimplified example, but you could use it as basis. Once the file is in CSV you can [load it with psql](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/importing-data-from-csv-in-postgresql/)

Comment: thanks for that. The expiry has the format of " Expires: Sat, 30 Oct 02021 13:01:57 +0100". How can we trim that to "Oct 2021" for all occurrences?